# Resolving procedure confusion when using OOP

Tags: oop, fortran

I am writing a vector type in Fortran and am getting very confused.

Suppose I have the following derived type

```
Type (Vector)
Real :: x, y
Contains  
  Procedure :: vector_smul
End Type 

Function vector_smul  &
  (                   &
    va, vb            &
  )                   &
    Result (c)

  Real :: c
  Class (Vector), Intent (In) :: va, vb

  c = (va%x + vb%x) + (va%y * vb%y)

End Function vector_smul
```

However when I use

```
Type (Vectors)
Real :: x, y
Contains  
  Procedure :: smul => vector_smul
End Type
```

I get an error when I use

```
Program Test
  Use Vector
  Implicit None
  Real :: c
  Type (Vector) :: va, vb 
  c = smul (va, vb)
End Program
```

Comment: What is your exact problem ? Where / by what are you getting confused ?

Comment: Ok, I have now replicated the problem. If I do this as shows I do not get a problem. However when I use `Procedure :: smul => vector_smul` and then call  `c = smul (va, vb)` I get the error `Function 'smul' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just defining a type-bound procedure `xyz%smul` that points to `vector_smul`! The original module procedure `vector_smul` is not effected!

To stay in the terminology of the Fortran Standard (2008, ch. 4.5.5), `smul` is the *binding name* for the *procedure name* `vector_smul`. You still can access the procedure itself.

You can "rename" the function when using it in the main program:

```
Program Test
  Use Vector, only: Vector, smul => vector_smul
  Implicit None
  Real :: c
  Type (Vector) :: va, vb 
  c = smul (va, vb)
End Program
```

[Although it is not possible to have the same name for the type different and the module, i.e. not name them both *Vector*...]

Take a look at the [corresponding topic at the Fortran Wiki](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Object-oriented+programming)...

Comment: So the problem occurs because `smul` is a member function, is that correct? Yes, the module and the derived type must have a different name.

Comment: Yes, `smul` does not exits outside the derived type.

Comment: However I can still use `c = vector_smul (va, vb)`. How does this happen as I am not calling it as a member function this way.

Comment: You are now calling the *original function* directly, not the type-bound procedure.

Comment: If I have a subroutine, would that hold true as well?